# Color picker in Visual Studio Code only shows saturation wheel, not colorful wheels

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colorbox

[image: Color Picker Screenshot]

I'm experiencing an issue with my color picker in Visual Studio Code. When I hover over the color box, it only shows the saturation wheel, and the other colorful wheels are missing. I've tried uninstalling the extension and restarting VS Code, but the problem persists. I'm unsure how to proceed in fixing this problem.

Comment: Welcome! I cannot reproduce this issue. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.